# Change values in one column base on data another column

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I update values from one column to another in the same table?
Say I have:

```
ID   |    GROUPNAME   |   GROUPNAME 1
010617   010617_ADMIN   010617_group
010618   010618_ADMIN   010618_group
```

I mean from the ID it should take the value and from group name and group name 2 in that order.I have nearly some 2000 record.Just want to execute in one query.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which database you are uisng?

Comment: You want to put data from `groupname` to `groupname1` and replace `_admin` in to `_group` ?

Comment: Oracle Database

Comment: Nope.From the ID i need to insert values into group name and group name 1.

Comment: the `ID` is exist data and 2 `groupname` is null?

Comment: No difficult, but a very odd thing to do.

Comment: Provide the sql statements you have tried already and the challenge you faced in those

Comment: Just use an `UPDATE` statement with string concatenation

Comment: yes we will have only ID values from that we need to insert values to other two column.and the order should be ID_ADMIN for one column and ID_group for other coulmn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourtable SET groupname = CONCAT(ID,'_ADMIN'), groupname1 = CONCAT(ID,'_group')
```

with conditions

```
    UPDATE yourtable SET groupname = CONCAT(ID,'_ADMIN'), groupname1 = CONCAT(ID,'_group') WHERE ...
```

Comment: That's invalid SQL. `"_ADMIN"` is an identifier. String constants need to be put into single quotes in SQL, e.g. `'_ADMIN'`

Comment: It's still invalid standard SQL and the question is for Oracle, not MySQL (and you should stop using non-standard SQL in MySQL as well, in case you ever have the chance to work with different, more standard compliant databases)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your advice

Comment: Its Working.Thank BRO..!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider usng a virtual column for this

eg

```
create table XXXXX

(
    ID VARCHAR2(5),
    GROUPNAME as ("ID"||'_ADMIN')
)
```

Comment: if this is of interest see:  https://viralpatel.net/blogs/oracle-11g-new-feature-virtual-column/